# What happens to Mac applications if the developer's distribution certificate expires?

Tags: macos, certificate, code-signing, software-distribution

My "Mac App Distribution" certificate will expire in a couple of weeks. When this happens, will my applications cease to function properly?

*This has been asked a lot, except in my situation, my applications are not distributed through the Mac App Store.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Users can still download, install, and run versions of your Mac apps that were signed with your certificate before it expired. However, you’ll need new Developer ID certs to sign updates and create new apps.

> Developer ID signatures carry cryptographic timestamps by default.
>   Signatures with cryptographic timestamps are validated against the
>   signing time, and signatures made with expired (at signing time)
>   certificates are invalid.

- [OS X Code Signing In Depth](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2206/_index.html)
- [Replacing Expired Certificates](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html)